# Python Mocking - How to mock sqlalchemy query?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, python-unittest, mysql-python

I want to try mocking my SQL query

So far I've mocked the DB connection and validation but have not gotten any idea how to mock the query.

Here's my function which I'm calling to execute queries

**query_functions.py**

```
CONST_INSERT = "INSERT INTO user (user_name, password, email_address, dob, address, uid ) VALUES(:user_name , :password, :email_address, :dob, :address, :uid)"

def connection():

    engine = create_engine('mysql://root:admin@172.17.0.2:3306/flask', poolclass = NullPool)
    conn = engine.connect()
    return conn

def run_insert(data):
    conn = connection()
    sql = text(CONST_INSERT)
    conn.execute(sql, data)
    conn.close()
    return ("executed")
```

This is what I've tried

**test.py**

```
 @patch.object(query_functions, 'connection')   
    def test_service_reg_return_correct_data(self, mock_sqlalchmey):
        data = {                                                              
            "user_name": "testuser56",
            "password": "123456",
            "email_address": "testuser56@example.com",
            "dob": "2022-06-07 00:00:00",
            "address": "Ahmedabad",
            
        }
        
        # json_data = json.dumps(data)
        # print("jsob", json_data)
        m1 = mock.MagicMock()
        m1.get_json.return_value = data

        
        
        print("m", m1)
        with mock.patch("backened.routes.register.request", m1):
            
            response =user_register() 
            self.assertTrue(mock_sqlalchmey.called)
            self.assertEqual(response.json, {'Message': 'New user Created'},201)
```

I'm calling **run_insert()** inside **user_register()**

```
def user_register():
         *** some code
      validate=  validate():
         *** some code
      insert = run_insert()
```

Comment: [Would this be of any help?](https://github.com/rajivsarvepalli/mock-alchemy)

Comment: @Undesirable this is not good for queries

Comment: Does this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74771974/python-mock-how-to-mock-a-method-inside-a-fucntion) helps you?